# Uninitialized constant "Controller Name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an error with my routes/resources and controllers.

I have the following in the routes.rb:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do  
  resource :schedule  
end
```

And I have a schedule_controller.rb inside controllers/users/ set up as I think it should be:

```
class Users::ScheduleController < ApplicationController

  # Controller methods here...

end
```

Running a rake:routes shows

```
user_schedule      POST   /users/:user_id/schedule(.:format)       schedules#create
new_user_schedule  GET    /users/:user_id/schedule/new(.:format)   schedules#new
edit_user_schedule GET    /users/:user_id/schedule/edit(.:format)  schedules#edit
                   GET    /users/:user_id/schedule(.:format)       schedules#show
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/schedule(.:format)       schedules#update
```

However, navigating to /users/:user_id/schedule is returning the following error:

```
uninitialized constant SchedulesController
```

My only thoughts on what the problem could be are that is has something to do with nested resources or declaring a single resource and I'm going wrong somewhere.

I'm using the helper

```
new_user_schedule_path(current_user)
```

when linking to my 'new' view.

Comment: Observe that ScheduleController is not SchedulesController.

Comment: I arrived at this question searching for the error in the title but not having the _nested_ vs _namespaced_ resource problem. In my case **the controller file was not placed in the correct folder**.

Comment: In my case the controller filename was not in the correct format. The filename should be "schedules_controller.rb"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be `SchedulesController`, not `Users::ScheduleController`. Controllers should only be namespaced when the route is [namespaced with `namespace`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-namespace). Controller names should also always be plural.

What you're creating is a [*nested* resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), not a namespaced one.

Comment: The singular resource example in the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) has a plural class name, so I expect that Andrew's right, and your controller name should be plural.

Comment: Sometimes the plurals are wrong, especially for complex plurals or compound words. In those cases you can change your inflections.rb file so rails looks for the 'plural'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was indeed confusing nested resources and namespacing. Also, using a singular 'schedule' was also causing problems.

Answer (score 6):

Is the namespacing of the `SchedulesController` intentional? i.e. do you *really* mean to do this?

```
class Users::SchedulesController < ApplicationController
```

Or are you only doing that because schedules are a "sub-thing" from users?

The reason I ask this is because typically within Rails, nested resource controllers *aren't* namespaced. You would only namespace a controller if you wanted to modify the controllers in a special way under a namespace. A common example of this would be having some controllers under an admin namespace, inheriting from a `BaseController` within that namespace that would restrict only admins from acessing those controllers.

#### Option 1

If you *didn't intentionally* namespace this controller, then you want to remove the `Users::` prefix from your controller, and move it back to `app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb`, the helpers back to `app/helpers/schedules_helper.rb` and the views back to `app/views/schedules`. Perhaps you ran a generator which also generated a `Users::Schedule` model, which should also need to be renamed to `Schedule` and moved back to `app/models/schedule.rb`.

#### Option 2

If you *did intentionally* namespace this controller, then you want to do this in your routes:

```
namespace :users do
  resources :schedules
end
```

Leave everything that's been generated as it should be.

Answer (score 5):

In your routes.rb you need to specify the controller like this:

```
resources :users do
  resource :schedules, controller: 'users/schedules'
end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it seems like the original ask was for a nested resource - not a namespaced one.  If you do not specify the controller in your nested resource like what's been done here, you will receive the error the original poster encountered.

Answer (score 0):

replace resources :users to
namespace :users

Because your schedule controller is inside users folder.
class Users::ScheduleController < ApplicationController
  # Controller methods here...
end