# Rails: No route matches... missing required keys: [:element_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, models, controllers

So, basically, I have `Features` nested within `Elements` which is nested within `Apps`. The `Apps` show page contains a Table of `Elements`, and each Element has a table of `Features`. I know that this will look a bit messy, but I'm more worried about functionality right now, and I'll clean up the HTML later.

**Full error:**
    Showing ~/app/views/apps/show.html.erb where line #41 raised:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"apps/elements/features",     
:element_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:element_id]
```

**My FeaturesController (only a few methods shown for the sake of space)**

```
class Elements::FeaturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_feature, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /features
  # GET /features.json
  def index
    @features = Feature.all
    respond_with(@features)
  end

  # GET /features/1
  # GET /features/1.json
  def show
    respond_with(@element.features)
  end

  # GET /features/new
  def new
    @element = Element.find(params[:element_id])
    @feature.element = @element
    @feature = Feature.new
  end

  # GET /features/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /features
  # POST /features.json
  def create
    @element = Element.find(params[:element_id])
    @feature = Feature.new(feature_params)
    @feature.element = @element
    @feature.save

    if @feature.save
      flash[:notice] = "#{@feature.name} purchase was added to the #{@feature.element.name}."
      redirect_to(@feature)
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding the purchase."
      render :show
    end
  end
```

**My show.html.erb for Apps:**

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <p>
   <strong>Name:</strong>
   <%= @app.name %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <strong>Infivewords:</strong>
   <%= @app.infivewords %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <strong>Description:</strong>
   <%= @app.description %>
 </p>

        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
                <tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
          <% @app.elements.each do |element| %>
                  <tr>
              <td><h4><%= element.name %></h4><br><h4><%= element.description %></h4></td>

              <td>
                <% element.features.each do |feature| %>
              <td><h4><%= feature.name %></h4><h4><%= feature.description %></h4>
              </td>

              <% end %>

              <td><h4><%= link_to "Delete", [@app, element], method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %></h4></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Add a Feature', new_element_feature_path(@element), class: 'pull-right' %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
<br>

        <br>
        <%= link_to 'Add an Element', new_app_element_path(@app) %>
        <br>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_app_path(@app) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', apps_path %>
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :apps do
    resources :elements, controller: 'apps/elements'
  end

  resources :elements do
      resources :features, except: [:index], controller: 'apps/elements/features'
  end

  root to: 'apps#index'
```

Please excuse the mess. I'm new to rails and I've been tearing my code apart trying to figure this out. Please let me know if I should post any more code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the path inside

```
<td><%= link_to 'Add a Feature', new_element_feature_path(@element), class: 'pull-right' %></td>
```

to

```
new_element_feature_path(element)
```

since you are still looping `@app.elements`, right?

Comment: Actually, I've tried that before. I've tried just about ever param I can think of. I just tried it again for good measure and get this:

`uninitialized constant Elements

Rails.root: C:/Users/Nick/Amnesia_Rails/Features

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/apps/elements/features_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>``

Which makes no sense to me because I'm inside the @app.elements loop still, so I don't get how its not initialized!

Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I think this is next error. Do have nested resources in your routes.rb, like `resources :elements do resource :features end`? If yes, then controller name should be `FeaturesControllers`, not `Elements::FeaturesControllers`  (read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115662/uninitialized-constant-controller-name), If not, add part of routes.rb related to elements and freatures.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the routes file. Note: I used to have my Features inside my Elements inside my Apps in my routes, but it got too messy, and I thought the correct way to handle it was as I posted above.

After changing `Elements::Features` to just `Features`, I got the following error when at `~/features/new`:

`superclass mismatch for class FeaturesController

Extracted source (around line #1):
          
class FeaturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_feature, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /features
  # GET /features.json
  def index`

Comment: My bad, with `controller: 'apps/elements' etc` in your routes.rb the namespacing was correct.

Comment: Any idea what I should be looking for then?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In view, changed params to `@element.feature`:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Feature', new_app_element_feature_path(@element.feature), class: 'pull-right' %>
```