# Uninitialized constant {"contrller name"}Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create a new page in my Rails view.

My view is: histories/index.html.erb

My controller is: process_controller.rb

The new page I am trying to create is: histories_paid_out

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
  get "process/histories_paid_out" => "process/histories_paid_out", :as => "histories_paid_out"
```

And in my process_controller.rb, I have:

```
  def histories_paid_out()
    payments = Payments.all
  end
```

And then finally I am calling the controller in my view like this:

```
<% @histories.each do |history| %>
  <%= link_to 'View paid out payments', histories_paid_out_path() %>
<% end %>
```

But when I cliked the "View paid out payments" link, my Rails app gave me this error:

[image]

What's wrong? It is so weird because I think my configuration and setup is already correct.

Comment: Your models are usually singular, not plural. Try `Payment.all` without the "s"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninitialized constant "Controller Name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115662/uninitialized-constant-controller-name). Also, I think you have an error in your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the singular version of the model. Try this:

```
def histories_paid_out()
    payments = Payment.all
end
```

Also you will need to define the `histories` variable somewhere.

Finally, `payments` will not be available in your view unless you change the scope by calling it `@payments` instead.