# uninitialized constant UsersController Did you mean? UserController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to Ruby on Rails in general!

I have this problem where I created a new user with a unique profile username and got this error below afterwards!
[image]

I added these gems, Devise, name_of_person, and friendly_id.

This's my code so far below:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show], param: :slug
  root "static#home"
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

User model

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_person_name
  
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

Application, statice and user controller

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end
end
```

static_controller.rb

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:slug])
  end
end
```

Registrations and sessions views files

edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Sessions
new.html.erb

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I hope this explains my problem!

Comment: Change the name of your `UserController` to `UsersController`.  Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13115662/2622934

Comment: Change it to UsersController and I still got the same error?!

Comment: Did you also change the file name to `users_controller.rb`?  And you may need to restart the Rails server.

Comment: Yes, I just did! I got this error "No template for interactive request
UsersController#show is missing a template for request formats: text/html"

Comment: Now you're going to need to make an `app/views/users/show.html.erb` file.  You'll want to check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html for more.

Comment: @cschroed Thank you so much! now it makes sense!

Comment: Good luck!  I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of the other one I mentioned.